# Bernoulli Trial variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics, bernoulli-numbers

> You are given n=10,000 light bulbs. Each has a reliability of p=99.99%
>   Suppose you select a batch of r=190 light bulbs to light your
>   warehouse. Can you use the equation to predict the probability of
>   having 189 good light bulbs out of this batch of 190?

[image]

I am confused here as to what is considered the number of trials and number of successes (given the assignment of variables)...

Any point in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to make an interpretation: is *exactly* $189$ intended, or is it *at least* $189$?

We take the first interpretation, though there is no strong argument for it. The probability that a bulb is bad is $0.0001=p$. So the probability of exactly one bad out of $190$ is given by
$$\binom{190}{1}p(1-p)^{189}.$$

**Another way:** This is a standard example of a setting where the **Poisson** approximation to the binomial is excellent. (If you have not covered the Poisson, then use the first solution.)

Here we have $n=190$. Let $\lambda=np$. The probability of one bad is approximately.
$$e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^1}{1!}.$$ 
In this case, the approximation is essentially dead on.

Comment: thank you, is the 10,000 negligible or why is it negligible?

Comment: We could make two interpretations (i) probability an individual bulb is bad is $0.0001$ or (ii) there is exatly one bad among the $10000$. Interpretation (i) is more reasonable. But even if we take interpretation (ii), $190$ bulbs is a small fraction of the $10000$, so sampling with replacement (binomial) or without (hypergeometric) give essentially the same answer